# Connect to user SCOTT by Oracle SQL developer

Tags: database

I tried to connect to user SCOTT with password admin, but got connection errors.

[image]

[image]

I have changed the password using ALTER USER SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting in the second screen shot ora-12505 isn't a username & password issue.  Double check your SID is typed correctly.  It would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of your working connection.

Your SID should relate to an entry in your tnsnames.ora file on your computer.  This file is typically found in `<your oracle directory>/Network/Admin/`  You can find it by searching your C:\ for *.ora

Comment: I added my screenshot as a new post below, please check that, thanks.

Comment: In your SID, you've put xe.  There's no corresponding entry in your tns names file.  Try using ORCL or LISTENER_ORCL